# How to get the ConnectionStatus of a VPN with "Get-VpnConnection" PowerShell command sent with Runtime.exec()?

Tags: java, powershell, vpn, runtime.exec

In my Java code I want to be sure that after adding a VPN via PowerShell command and after calling rasdial to connect to it, it's actually connected.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();                  
try {                   
    String command = "powershell.exe Add-VpnConnection -Name \"ProxyConnector\" -ServerAddress \""+serverAddress+":"+port+"\" ";
    rt.exec(command);
    String command2 = "rasdial.exe ProxyConnector "+username+" "+password;
    rt.exec(command2);                          
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I know that the command `Get-VpnConnection -Name %VpnName%` gives all the information about the VPN (if exist), but how do I take just the value ConnectionStatus? And is it actually reliable for my purpose?

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Comment: Really much thanks, that guide you linked to me was really exhaustive and well explained why all those approach were good or bad. And yes thanks i also noticed that i can improve how i pass commands into the exec()